# Why did I get a blank page after using Django_ajax with django?

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm a beginner in django, I follow the steps showed at [GitHub](https://github.com/yceruto/django-ajax),  but I just got a blank page, here my code:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django_ajax.decorators import ajax
@ajax
def AjaxView(request):
    return render(request, 'blogs/ajaxtest.html'`
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^ajax/', 'blogs.views.AjaxView', name='Ajax'))
```

**ajaxtest.html**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/blogs/django_ajax/js/jquery.ajax.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <title>Ajax Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    ajaxGet('/', function(content){
        //onSuccess
        alert(content);
    })
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You should really accept the answer provided by Adrian.

Comment: can u post the corrected version for my reference...thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You need to include jQuery before django_ajax or django_ajax won't work, it is a requirement.
Also your AjaxView function seems to be incomplete.

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. It works.but I also forgot to load static files.